# Identifying details despite an NDA as a third party (California)

Tags: united-states, california, non-disclosure-agreement

If a potential employee were to claim that they worked for a company that was sold but their NDA prevents them from speaking about their company name, the buying company's name, and details about what their company does, how would the hiring manager/hiring company (a third party to the NDA and the original buy/sell) find out/verify details of this?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - No, I simply worked there for a while and the owner unexpectedly sold the company. I was not allowed to say I worked for the company while there publicly (no linkedin nor does my name come up). I'm unsure how to list this on my resume in a way that it is provable when looking for later employment

Comment: @wavt: isn't that just a duplicate of https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/192408/listing-company-on-resume-where-nda-prevents-company-name ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listing company on resume where NDA prevents company name](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/192408/listing-company-on-resume-where-nda-prevents-company-name)

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are being interviewed for a C level management position, the actual company is immaterial. A hiring manager should be interested in your competency for the position. That can be done via directed interview questions. You can talk about what you did, how you did it, and the challenges you faced.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways.

- You could use publications, articles etc that were created before the company was sold.
- If your name was on the company's website, the wayback engine would show your name on it
- An old email trail may have your old company details/logo
- The Company registry (I assume there is one in your country) will have information on it.  A search for directors will soon find the company.  You dont have to mention the Company Name,

Apart from that, you are stuffed.

Comment: Would it not be registered somewhere (the company and/or the sale)?

Answer (score 2):

As a hiring manager, a claim like that would look to me like the claim of a 13 year old teenage boy that he indeed has a real girlfriend, but I would not know her because she goes to another school.

I can't imagine a legitimate reason why someone would expect employees to be *that* secretive about their involvement in this company. Not divulging business secrets? OK, that's understandable. Not admitting that they were ever even involved in it? Sorry, but that's bullshit.

Comment: A comment from the OP "clarifies" that they were merely an employee at the company.

Comment: This is exactly my concern. The reasons for the NDA signing are many (very small company got sold to a country development fund and I think the more stringent NDA is put in place to ensure it would be harder for us to find jobs in the same industry/role, but the company was ok with it because we got a large valuation multiple during buyout), but I don't know how to communicate this without sounding like a liar. I can answer technical questions of course, but I'm unsure about how I would get to that point in the interview process.

Comment: Why did *you* sign the NDA?

Comment: @PhilipKendall This was a condition of the sale. The company was a small company and the monetary incentive to sign the NDA was large (I made 5 years of salary instantly)

Comment: @wavt, 5 years of salary certainly "smoothes over" the absurdity of the demands. But 5 years of salary for simply abiding is a huge sum *unless* we're talking about a developing world salary paid for by a foreign/multinational company that doesn't mind being unreasonable. Oh wait, California? This question is fishy!

Comment: @teego1967 - Signing the NDA was a deal of the sale. The NDA was extremely restrictive in other areas as well, but this is the only are I'm asking about. Because it was a small company, every knew each other and I wasn't going to turn down such a large sum of money because of a slightly more restrictive NDA. I agree it is unusual, but I'm unsure how I can prove it to you, short of publishing the NDA